# Spark - How to deal with columns that have blank space in the name

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to know how to access an attribute from a `Row` that has a blank space in the name.

For example, I have this `Row` object

```
Row(ONE CATEGORY=u'category')
```

How can I access the `ONE CATEGORY` value. Normally I would use `row.oneCategory` to access it, but in this case that's not possible because of the blank space. If possible, I prefer the suggestions in Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```py
row = Row("ONE CATEGORY")("category")
row
## Row(ONE CATEGORY='category')
getattr(row, u"ONE CATEGORY")
## 'category'
```

or `Row.asDict` method:

```py
row.asDict()["ONE CATEGORY"]
## 'category'
```

Since you cannot use dot syntax in Scala it is not really an issue, but if you want to access fields by name you can use `Row.getAs`

```scala
val row = sc.parallelize(Tuple1("category") :: Nil).toDF("ONE CATEGORY").first
row.getAs[String]("ONE CATEGORY")
```

or `Row.getValuesMap`:

```scala
row.getValuesMap[String](Seq("ONE CATEGORY"))("ONE CATEGORY")
```

In both Python and Scala, you can access value by index:

```py
## row[0]
'category'
```

```scala
row(0)
// Any = category
row.getString(0)
// String = category
```

Finally you can use `alias` method during select to avoid the issue completely:

```
df.select(col("ONE CATEGORY").alias("ONE_CATEGORY"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL you can use

```
``
```

to show columns with spaces in between.
Please make sure you don't confuse '' with ``.

Answer (score 0):

you could replace spaces or any undesired characters like:

```
import re
import pyspark
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

def format_colname(text):
    rep = {" ": "", ".": "", "_":""} # define desired replacements here
    # format : {<remove-this-pattern> : <insert-this-pattern> }

    # use these three lines to do the replacement
    rep = dict((re.escape(k), v) for k, v in rep.iteritems())
    pattern = re.compile("|".join(rep.keys()))
    text = pattern.sub(lambda m: rep[re.escape(m.group(0))], text)
    return text

exprs = [sf.col(column).alias(format_colname(column)) for column in data.columns]
print(exprs)

data = data.select(*exprs)
```

or if you have just one pattern then

```
 exprs = [sf.col(column).alias(column.replace(" ", "") for column in data.columns]
 data = data.select(*exprs)
```