# How to get a value of a row in spark using python

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I want to get a value stored in a dataframe. Not printed with .show(), store it into a variable. I don't want to use Pandas, just Spark dataframes. I am new to spark, although this seems kind of basic, stackoverflow is not helping.

```
average = (myDF
            .groupBy()
            .mean()
            )

print average
```

The goal is that "print average" prints the float, and I can operate with it.
A general method to get values of rows/colums would be appreciate as well. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a general method to take any other value?

Comment: See [Spark - How to deal with columns that have blank space in the name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32365853/1560062) for all possible ways to access. And please search before asking.

Comment: That last one was what I was looking for. All the post that I have seen before were using Pandas code. Thank you!